# Array value to check with comma separated values in table and return all row if single match with values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a array i.e.

```
$frame = Array(
   [0]=1,
   [1]=2,
   [2]=4 
);
```

and I want to get value form table "standard_product" where "frame_category" is a column name, this column value are look like
frame_category
4,7
1,3,4
6,7,8
return all row if any value of $frame match with any value of frame_category column. Here require result is: 
4,7
1,3,4

My effort to resolve this is:

```
Standard_product::Where('frame_category', 'LIKE', '%' . $frame . '%')->get()->toArray();
(SELECT * FROM  `standard_products` WHERE  `frame_category` LIKE  "%".$frame."%");
```

but i will not return expected result. Please help me.

Comment: There can't be 2 keys 0 in your array..

Comment: Looks like your array has duplicate keys..... which can't exist in PHP

Comment: Bad database design, but [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).... otherwise you'll get results for that match `14`, `42`, etc as well as those that match `4`.... and as the db can't use indexes for this type of search, it won't ever be a fast query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `toArray()` last in the query

```
Standard_product::where('frame_category', 'LIKE', '%'.$frame.'%')->get();
```

or

```
Standard_product::like('frame_category', '%$frame%')->get();
```

Or

```
$category = DB::table('Standard_product')
          ->where('frame_category', 'like', '%$frame%')
          ->get();
```

[Where Clauses In laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: thanks for your solution but it will not return required result.

Comment: In above example i was got null array as a result.

Comment: is database have data??

Comment: It will work only if sub string of $frame found in database column

Comment: But i need to get all row if any of the value of $frame match with database column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94592/discussion-between-aman-singh-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL `IN`

```
$ids = join(',', $frame);
WHERE  frame_category IN ($ids)
```

Passing Your to array to MySQL like that

Answer (score 1):

```
$frame = Array( [0]=1, [1]=2,[0]=4 );
foreach ($frame as $val) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `standard_products` WHERE find_in_set(".$val.", frame_category)");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$result[] = $row;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this is too heavy for me. because it will take much more time to run.

Comment: If it takes too long to run, then normalize your database properly and you won't need expensive FIND_IN_SET queries.... you designed your database badly in the first place.... the real fix is to correct the design, not use an inefficient workround